# how to create checkboxlist inside the html table

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, vb.net

`Dim data As New SqlDataAdapter` 
       `Dim ds As New DataSet` 
        `Dim df As New DataTable` 
     `Dim dt As New DataTable` 
      `Dim cblbind As New CheckBoxList` 
      `Dim strcon As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("sample").ConnectionString` 
        `Dim con As New SqlConnection(strcon)` 
       `Dim CmdString As String = "select Teamid,teamname from team"` 
       `Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(CmdString, con)` 
       `data.SelectCommand = cmd` 
       `con.Open()` 
       `data.SelectCommand = cmd` 
        `data.Fill(dt)` 
      `For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1` 
       `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` 
            `Dim protyp As Integer = dt.Rows(i).Item("TeamId")` 
            `cmd.Connection = con` 
           `cmd.CommandText = "TeamBindingProc"` 
           `cmd.Parameters.Add("@TeamId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = protyp` 
           `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` 
            `data.SelectCommand = cmd` 
           `data.Fill(ds)` 
            `Dim HtmlStr As String = ""` 
           `HtmlStr += "<table border='1' align='center'>"` 
          `HtmlStr += "<tr>"` 
  `HtmlStr += "<th>" + "TeamName" + "</th>"` 
         `HtmlStr += "<th>" + "TeamMember" + "</th>"` 
 `HtmlStr += "</tr>"` 
           `For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows` 
               `HtmlStr += "<tr>"`

```
           ` HtmlStr += "<td>" + dr("TeamName").ToString() + "</td>"`
           ` HtmlStr += "<td>" + dr("Nickname").ToString() + "</td>"`
           ` HtmlStr += "</tr>"`
       ` Next`

       ` HtmlStr += "</table>"`
     `   literal1.Text = HtmlStr`
    `Next`
    ' Next
```

I Marked Like Bold in this coding I want to Checkboxlist for that Lines.. how to do it?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achive.? First, the way you are appending the string "HtmlStr" is not  a best parctice to bind data to the screen. You must try to use the ASP.NET controls.

Comment: actually already i did using asp controls but my team leader said without asp create html table and bind to database i am the beginner so only i dont know... if u know means help me

Comment: A Checkboxlist does not exists in html, you'll have to use normal checkbox  <input type="checkbox" />